# SHA-256 of concatenation byte+string+byte

Tags: java, string-concatenation

1) if in PHP i've got this code:

```
$var = "\x00\x23\x21\x11";
```

How i should write this statement in Java?

2) when I need to concatenate 3 types of variables, two of this bytes and a string, and than get the SHA-256 digest.

I do

```
String all = varbyte1+varstr1+varbyte2;
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
byte[] digest = md.digest(all.getBytes("UTF-8"));
String hash = String.format("%0" + (digest.length*2) + "X", new BigInteger(1, digest));
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong, as you would probably notice if you looked at your `all`:

```
    String x = "meh";
    byte b = 39;
    byte c = 99;
    String y = b + x + c ;
    System.out.print(y);
```

prints `39meh99`. I'd suggest using a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) and writing the three parts in three calls to `stream.write`.

In general, you should get used to the fact that Strings in Java are not byte arrays since the distinction between `char` and `byte` is pretty solidly enforced, so you always should think about which encoding you use to convert between the two.

Comment: ok. but if I wanted to put a mac address into a variable in php I do

$var = "\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05";
what type of variable should be instantiated IN JAVA and how I can initialize it?

Comment: Byte array! byte[] mac = new Byte[0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05].

Comment: Eh, yes, very sorry, it shows that I do Scala at work :)
byte[] mac = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x05};

Comment: yes :) i should write for values as 0xc1 this right? byte[] mac = {(byte)0xC1,(byte)0x8E,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x04,(byte)0x05};

Answer (score -1):

Part 1 I can answer.

`$var = "\\x00\\x23\\x21\\x11";`

Comment: this is for php but in java if i have String var = "\\x00\\x23\\x21\\x11"; and print it i don't get the same output of php code! :D this for one reason, in php the variabiles don't require the type! :|